# Error 10053 on wampserver after sleeping the computer

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, sleep, wamp

I use WampServer for development testing purposes on my local computer (windows 8). I don't usually turn off the computer, I just close the cover (a laptop) and it sleeps. When I open it again, the server icon in the taskbar is still green, showing that everything is running, but when I try to connect to my server, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error on line 9 in file C:\...\server\connect.inc 
Error: PDO::__construct(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=10053 
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

The error is occurring when I connect to the MySQL server, with the following code:

```
$conn=new PDO($mysqlhoststring, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword, 
        array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

If I restart all services in WampServer, then it works again.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the system goes to sleep it's going to abort connections; perhaps a hibernate would solve the 'status is green but it doesn't work' issue. My guess is that the service is running but some of the connections which aborted on sleep are unaware that they failed on resume.

I would suggest modifying the power settings to keep the laptop on (just turn off display) on lid close actions or, if uptime isn't important, to try hibernating. The first option will prevent the error your are experiencing but will reduce battery life some.

Comment: It's a completely new connection started only after the computer was turned back on. It has no problem connecting to the webserver, only the MySQL server is giving issues. I can't leave it on the whole time - I might leave it overnight, and it's not always plugged in. I don't see how hibernating will help me, either way I'd have to restart the server, no?

Comment: My only thought was that the state that the server comes back from will be slightly different than how it comes back from sleep and that may be enough to resolve the issue. It should come back 'cleaner' from hibernate. Maybe give it a shot?

Comment: That worked, thanks. I don't have enough reputation on superuser to upvote it...

Comment: No prob, glad it worked. Hibernate takes a bit longer because of how it handles the memory which is active, it's much more reliable than sleep =)

Comment: I know it takes longer, but it takes even longer to restart wampserver, and almost every time I use the computer I have to use it.

Comment: I wonder if others experience the same issue. I couldn't find it anywhere from searching.

Comment: It didn't work again :( Seems like it's not full-proof solution.